# AlertManager alerts - need the way to add into mail template how long alert already fired and sort alerts by this filed

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

When I add .StartsAt filed into AlertManager mail template I get the following representation in mail:

> 2023-01-12 00:03:03.584 +0000 UTC

But I need to display how long time each alert already fired and sort them by this field.
I know Go templates have function Since(), but unfortunately it isn't available in AlertManager mail templates.
As a workaround - how to sort on StartsAt field?